# In the Go programming language, is it possible to obtain a variable's type as a string?

Tags: go

I'm fairly unfamiliar with the Go programming language, and I've been trying to find a way to get the type of a variable as a string. So far, I haven't found anything that works. I've tried using `typeof(variableName)` to obtain a variable's type as a string, but this doesn't appear to be valid.

Does Go have any built-in operator that can obtain a variable's type as a string, similar to JavaScript's `typeof` operator or Python's `type` operator?

```
//Trying to print a variable's type as a string:
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    num := 3
    fmt.Println(typeof(num))
    //I expected this to print "int", but typeof appears to be an invalid function name.
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's the [`TypeOf`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) function in the [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

func main() {
    num := 3
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(num))
}
```

This outputs:

```
int
```

**Update:** You updated your question specifying that you want the type as a string.  `TypeOf` returns a `Type`, which has a `Name` method that returns the type as a string.  So

```
typeStr := reflect.TypeOf(num).Name()
```

**Update 2:** To be more thorough, I should point out that you have a choice between calling `Name()` or `String()` on your `Type`; they're sometimes different:

```
// Name returns the type's name within its package.
// It returns an empty string for unnamed types.
Name() string
```

versus:

```
// String returns a string representation of the type.
// The string representation may use shortened package names
// (e.g., base64 instead of "encoding/base64") and is not
// guaranteed to be unique among types.  To test for equality,
// compare the Types directly.
String() string
```

Answer (score 14):

If you just want to print the type then: `fmt.Printf("%T", num)` will work. http://play.golang.org/p/vRC2aahE2m